# jQuery Select2 TypeError: b is undefined

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2, codeigniter-3

I am using `jQuery (1.12.4)` and `Select2 (4.0.3)` to select multiple values from DB but I'm getting following error.

> TypeError: b is undefined

JS Code

```
    $('#country').select2(
    {
        placeholder: '--- Select ---',
        multiple: true,
        ajax:
        {
            url: '<?=site_url()?>/countries',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            delay: 1000,
            processResults: function (data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                var myResults = [];
                $.each(data, function (index, item)
                {
                    myResults.push(
                    {
                        'id': item.id,
                        'text': item.text
                    });
                });
                return
                {
                    results: myResults
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
```

JSON Response

```
[
    {
      "id": "US",
      "text": "United States"
    },
    {
      "id": "RE",
      "text": "Reunion"
    },
    {
      "id": "TZ",
      "text": "Tanzania, United Republic of"
    },
    {
      "id": "TN",
      "text": "Tunisia"
    },
    {
      "id": "AE",
      "text": "United Arab Emirates"
    },
    {
      "id": "GB",
      "text": "United Kingdom"
    },
    {
      "id": "UM",
      "text": "United States minor outlying islands"
    }
]
```

HTML is quite simple

```
<select id="country"></select>
```

PHP Code

```
$this->db->like('name', $this->input->post("q"));
            $query = $this->db->select('code AS id, name as text')
                    ->limit(20)
                    ->get("countries");
            $records = $query->result();
echo json_encode($records);
```

Comment: It would help you if you included the unminified version of select2 when debugging so you can check where the error is exactly. That tends to give more hints as to what is going wrong.

Comment: @apokryfos thank you for suggestion. Yes it helps, now I got this error `TypeError: data is undefined`

Comment: @apokryfos `console.log(data);` is also not printing anything. But I can see response in FireBug. It seem strange :|

Comment: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax says there's a `data` entry in the ajax properties. Maybe it's mandatory rather than optional?

Comment: @apokryfos still did not get it :(